# CKAN ERROR 500 EVERY SUBMIT DATA

Tags: python, wsgi, ckan

I setup ckan 2.7.2 for development. I got problem, the server return error 500 every submit new or updated data (group, organization, dataset). Here is the output of ckan-default.error.log

```
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.261643 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29258:tid 140278908057344] 2017-10-31 23:05:58,261 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /group render time 0.110 seconds
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543091 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] 2017-10-31 23:05:58,542 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.003 seconds [Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543759 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363] mod_wsgi (pid=29257): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543801 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543822 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/__init__.py", line 136, in __call__ 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543861 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]     return self.apps[app_name](environ, start_response)
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543875 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/cascade.py", line 130, in __call__ 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543894 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]     return self.apps[-1](environ, start_response) 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543905 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/common_middleware.py", line 61, in __call__ 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543929 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]     return elf.app(environ, start_response) 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.543969 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/registry.py", line 379, in __call__ 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.544030 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]     app_iter = self.application(environ, start_response)
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.544049 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/repoze/who/middleware.py", line 117, in __call__ 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.544073 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363] wrapper.finish_response(remember_headers) 
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.544084 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/repoze/who/middleware.py", line 177, in finish_response
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.544110 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363] write = self.start_response(self.status, headers, self.exc_info)
[Tue Oct 31 23:05:58.544134 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29257:tid 140278908057344] [remote 127.0.0.1:34363] TypeError: expected byte string object, value of type unicode found
```

I wish for a troubleshoot to resolve the problem. Thanks

Comment: As the error says, you are returning a Unicode string as response content to request, rather than a normal string (which is also a byte string in Python 2).

Comment: any suggestion to solve it? any way when the error show, then I reload the page, but not by pressing F5 or Ctrl+R, the page get normal. Is it missconfiguration on wsgi config file or permission ?

Comment: Do you have a non-ascii character in your user account details? Try running CKAN using 'paster serve' and switch on 'debug' to investigate what the problem string is.

Comment: If in my apache2 ports.conf I put 2 listening ports, such as 8080 and 8123, could it caused the routing error?